# Github pages asset path leading to 404

Tags: image, github, http-status-code-404, markdown, jekyll

I am currently using a custom domain with GitHub pages and Jekyll. I have included an image in the about page by added

```
![alt text]({{ site.baseurl }}/assets/uploads/image.jpg "Optional title")
```

In the root of my jekyll folder I have a folder *assets* and another folder *uploads* with an *image.jpg* file inside. However, when I visit the page, loading the image gives a 404 because its path is *http://user.github.com/assets/uploads/image.jpg* or *http://domain.com/assets/uploads/image.jpg*. 
I think GitHub is thinking that I have a project called assets. How can I get around this an link to an image in my GitHub page repo? Thanks.

The site is at http://ansonliu.com and http://ansonl.github.io The page with image in question is at http://ansonliu.com/about

Comment: Can you give us the real url of your site ?

Comment: The site is at http://ansonliu.com and http://ansonl.github.io

The page with image in question is at http://ansonliu.com/about/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it ! Your image name is **secret-sidwalk.jpg** not **secret-sidewalk.jpg**.

Comment: Thanks! Always helps to have a second pair of eyes looking at things.